# undefined method `email' for #<Product:0xbc177fc> - Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm facing this problem I'm stuck with with Rails 3.2 and ruby 2.1

I'm using `ActiveAdmin` and `Devise` to add models to my admin area.

I've added my Product model like this:

```
rails g active_admin:resource Product
```

It creates the new menu in my admin area, and this is working right.

But when I try to save a new product it throws this error:

```
NoMethodError at /admin/products
undefined method `email' for #<Product:0xbc177fc>
```

This is my `Product.rb` model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, 
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

# Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
#attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
belongs_to :category
has_many :line_items
has_many :orders, through: :line_items

validates_presence_of :category_id, :name, :price_cents
#attr_accessible :avatar
#has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
#validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

attr_accessor :price

attr_accessible :category_id, :description, :image, :name, :price_cents, :upc_code, :price, :taxable

def price
  price_cents/100.0 if price_cents
end

def price= price
  self.price_cents = (price.to_f*100).round
end

end
```

I commented the `email` line but I'm still getting this error, any ideas?

This is my `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.12'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'zurb-foundation'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.3.0'

group :development do
  gem "better_errors"
  gem 'annotate'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

gem 'ember-rails'
gem 'ember-source', '~> 1.10'
gem 'handlebars-source', '~> 2.0.0'
gem 'active_model_serializers', '~>0.8.0'
gem 'filepicker-rails'

gem 'thin'
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'capistrano'
gem 'simple_form'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'

# File upload extension
gem "paperclip", "~> 4.3"

# Admin
gem 'activeadmin'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
undefined method `email' for #<Product:0xbc177fc>
```

The error means, it called the `email` method on a `product` object but could not find it. To make the `email` method available for the `product` object, you have to add the `:email` to `attr_accessor` list in your `Product` model.

Add `email` to your `Product` models' `attr_accessor` list:

```
attr_accessor :price, :email
```

In addition, if you want to update the `:email` attibute, then you also need to add `:email` to the `attr_accessible` list as well:

```
attr_accessible :category_id, :description, :image, :name, :price_cents, :upc_code, :price, :taxable, :email
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your awesome help, btw now it says "undefined method `email_changed?' ", I add :email_changed but I cannot add the '?' at the end, it would be invalid =/

Comment: Seems like a 'devise' thing, but it shouldn't give any problems

Comment: I've searched with sublime_text, this 'email_changed?' is only present on devise, not in my model, btw your answer is actually right, do you have any idea or should I open a new question?

Comment: I am on my way home. Not in front of the computer. I can take a look when I get home.

Comment: But I am sure somehow that method is being called. You need to figure out from the full stack track trace when that method is being  called